# MySQL scheme database builder

Tags: mysql, schema

I'm currently putting together (on old fashioned paper) a layout for my new database, but was told I should probably lay it out as a scheme, which is true.

Is there a tool that allows me to create my table structure/scheme in a plan type layout interface with all relationships and when it's finished it automagically creates the tables in the database and spits out the schema as a file I can print and share with others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/) sounds like just the ticket.

Comment: Looks good, any good quick start documentation/tutorials you are aware off?

Comment: I've used it without having to resort to docs or tutorials.  If you've used anything similar in the past, like another E/R or UML tool, it's pretty similar.  Drag the tables onto the page, name them, add columns, primary and foreign keys, cardinalities, and you're there.